# sniff and block packets in a server

Tags: networking, packet-sniffers, proxy-server

I'm new to the concept of nw-sniffing. < so , i'll try to describe the problem with the best terms i know >

In an organisation , there are 30 computers connected to a server. And as users of these systems browse the Internet , packets are sent to the outside nw via this server.. i want to write an application that runs in this server , that sniffs these packets , reads the Http requests , the IP addresses to analyse these packets and block those found objectionable.

Where to begin ? pl help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the objection in using existing software?

Comment: first , i dont know about any existing s/w. second , will i be able to call the modules or use the output of those existing softwares in my application.. < i am doing a project on URL classification and want to apply that in real time >.

Comment: There are any number of commercial and freeware programs that do this already: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Content-control_software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to begin would definately be theory. Look up how IP packets are built-up, what a HTTP packet looks like and how networks are structured at a low level. There's alot worth learning.

As far as tools for learning go, I'd highly recommend [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Allow you to perform DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) and get used to what you're after.

A common method of DPI is to use a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) server or similar proxy through which all traffic is filtered.

DPI has downsides. It will affect your network and, if naively implemented, can easily add a single point of failure.